# Understanding differences in imports when running locally vs installing from PyPI

Tags: python, python-import, pypi, python-packaging

I have created a package which has the following structure:

```
/data_worker/
    .git/
    data_worker/
        wrappers/
            alpha_vantage_wrapper.py
            quandl_wrapper.py
            wrapper.py
        __init__.py
        data_worker.py
        defined_wrappers.py
        mapper.py
    tests/
        test.py
    .gitignore
    LICENSE
    README.md
    requirements.txt
    setup.py
    test.py
```

`/data_worker/data_worker/data_worker.py` begins with the following lines:

```
from defined_wrappers import wrappers
import mapper

import pandas as pd
import json
import os

DATA_WORKER_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '/'


class DataWorker:
    ...
```

In `/tests/test.py`, I am testing running the package from a completely separate directory, as it would be done once I `pip install` the package.
I have the following:

```
from data_worker.data_worker import DataWorker

dw = DataWorker()
```

which runs fine with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kevin/Documents/data_worker/tests/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from data_worker.data_worker import DataWorker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/data_worker/data_worker.py", line 1, in <module>
    from defined_wrappers import wrappers
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'defined_wrappers'
```

So my question is:

How can I structure my project's imports so that it can be run without errors after installing from PyPI (or from my `tests` directory)?

Comment: `data_worker` is a package, so use `from .defined_wrappers import wrappers` or `from data_worker.defined_wrappers import wrappers`. Your mistake is having added the `data_worker/data_worker/` directory to `sys.path` somewhere (perhaps by running a script inside the package).

Comment: That worked, thanks!